# How can you prove that multiplication with floating-point numbers creates more inaccuracy than addition/subtraction?

Tags: python, floating-point

I just started reading about the inaccuracies with writing decimals in binary. Then I was given this challenge:

> You are given two functions which take float inputs a and b and returns the value `a ** 2 - b ** 2`. There are two ways to calculate this: `(a + b) * (a - b)` and `(a ** 2 - b ** 2)`. Both the calculations would give the same result when not performed in binary. Write a program that checks which of these functions give the most accurate result.

Here is my thought process:

The difference between the two functions is the fact that the second method performs two multiplications while the first method only performs one. I don’t know how multiplication and addition/subtraction is done internally in python. But both the methods perform a total of 3 mathematical operations, so if the second method gives a more inaccurate answer, this means multiplication creates more inaccuracy.

This could be done by comparing both the method results to a totally accurate answer, but I don’t have this unless I calculate the correct answer by hand. Does anyone know another method which could be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry if the math looks a little ugly. But mathjax can aperantly not be used on stack overflow.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how you can do infinite-precision calculations in order to compare two alternative floating-point calculations?

Comment: I don't understand what your "thought process" has to do with the challenge. It doesn't ask you to determine the answer by thinking about it, you're supposed to determine it by writing a program that compares the results.

Comment: So write a program what calls both versions of the function with known inputs and results, and compares the actual results with the expected results. Then see which one is closer.

Comment: "Write a program that checks which of these functions give the most accurate result." - can you write code that gets the result for each function? Can you write code that looks at a function's result vs. the correct result, and tells you how accurate it is? Can you write code that takes in the information about how accurate each function was, and tells you which one was more accurate? If you put these things together, does it not solve the problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: "but I don’t have this unless I calculate the correct answer by hand." Are you being asked to check it for someone else's `a` and `b` values, or do you get to choose them? The problem statement that you show only says that you are given the *functions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with "binary" so much as with that floating-point formats (regardless of base) have limited precision. For example, consider a decimal calculator that can only work with 4 significant digits. Let, say, `a = 999` and `b = 998`. Then `a+b` is computed exactly as `1997`, and `a-b` exactly as `1`, and their product is also exact: `1997`.

But, the other way, you're in trouble at once trying to compute `a**2` = `999*999` = `998001`. The caculator cnly stores the first 4 digits, so rounds to `9980e2`. `b**2` similarly rounds to `9960e2`. Their difference is `20e2`, and `2000` is not `1997`.

Do read the [Python docs appendix](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) on floating-point issues. As it suggests, if you want exact results you can often use the `fractions` or `decimal` modules instead.